# Not able to resolve webdriver in python selenium eclipse setup

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have gone through various links and performed the following steps:

1. Install Python
2. Install selenium with pip install selenium command
3. Run eclipse
4. Install PyDev plugin in Eclipse
5. Choose Python as an interpreter
6. In Libraries section, I have all the libraries installed

   [image: screen shot]
7. However when I try to use `import webdriver`, webdriver is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should import it as

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Try it and let me know the result